# How to dynamically set two attributes in a class in PhP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am experiencing an issue where the order-id and product-quantity attributes of the checkboxes do not change dynamically within the loop. I would appreciate guidance on how to code it in a manner that ensures their dynamic alteration within the loop.

I would like some assistance with this problem.

```js
function updateNonManquant(order_id, totalProducts)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < totalProducts; i++)
    {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(i);
        var product_id = checkbox.name;
        var button = checkbox.getAttribute("data-order-id");
        var product_quantity = checkbox.getAttribute("data-product-quantity");
        alert(order_id);
        alert(button);
        if (button.includes(order_id))
        {
            var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
            var xhr = makeRequest();
            var sql;

            if (checkbox.checked)
            {
                sql = `UPDATE article SET etat_stock = 1 WHERE id = ${product_id} AND num_commande = ${order_id}`;
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify({sql: sql}));

                xhr = makeRequest();

                sql = `UPDATE produit SET stock = stock - ${product_quantity} WHERE id = ${product_id}`;
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify({sql: sql}));
            } 
            else
            {     
                sql = `UPDATE article SET etat_stock = 0 WHERE id = ${product_id} AND num_commande = ${order_id}`;
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify({sql: sql}));
            }

            xhr = makeRequest();

            sql = `UPDATE commande SET etat_commande = 2, date_traitement = '${date}' WHERE num_commande = ${order_id}`;
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({sql: sql}));
        }
    }
    window.location.reload();
}

function makeRequest()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "db_query.php";

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
      {
        var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return xhr;
}
```

```php
<?php
    require_once "process_orders.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Commande Client</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="updateNonManquant_function.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        if ($number_of_orders == 0)
        {
            ?>

            <div class="centerPage">
                <h1>Aucun panier à traiter</h1>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <h1 class="centerMargin">Traitement des paniers</h1>
            <?php

            $checkbox_id = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_orders; $i++) 
            {
                ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3"><?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getName(); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Produit</th>
                        <th>Quantité</th>
                        <th><?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_date(); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $customerOrder[$i]->getTotalProducts(); $j++)
                    {
                        $product_name = $customerOrder[$i]->getProductName($j);
                        $product_quantity = $customerOrder[$i]->getProductQuantity($j);
                        $product_id = $customerOrder[$i]->getProductId($j);
                        $order_id = $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_id();
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $product_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product_quantity; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $product_id ;?>" 
                                    class="checkbox" 
                                    data-order-id="<?php echo $order_id; ?>" 
                                    data-product-quantity="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>"
                                    id="<?php echo $checkbox_id ?>" <?php if($customerOrder[$i]->getProductAvailable($j) == "true") { echo "checked"; } ?>></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $checkbox_id++;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </table>
                    <table style="border-color: transparent;">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" style="background-color : transparent;">
                            <button id="<?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_id(); ?>" onclick="updateNonManquant(<?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_id(); ?>, <?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getTotalProducts();?>)">Valider</button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
                <br> <br>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the attribute id is used inconsistently within your code, `id="<?php echo $checkbox_id ?>"` the `$checkbox_id` is relevant only to the order of execution, while when you try to process it you use `document.getElementById(i)` where var *i* comes from `for (let i = 0; i < totalProducts; i++)`, you should drop `$checkbox_id` entirely and for example use $order_id and $j pair for identification

Comment: please note that your code is vulnerable to sql injection attack, imagine someone executing `makeRequest().send(JSON.stringify({sql: 'DROP TABLE article'}));`